# Saving Pandas dataframe indices to file

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to save just the indices of a dataframe to a file. Here is what I've tried:

A)

```
np.savetxt("file_name", df.index.values)
```

returns:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

B)

```
df.index.values.tofile("file_name")
```

returns:

```
IOError: cannot write object arrays to a file in binary mode
```

C)

```
with open("file_name","w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(df_1_indexes.values.tolist()))
```

Can someone please explain why A) and B) failed? I'm at a loss.

Cheers

Comment: It would help us to know what kind of objects compose the index. Please post `df.head().index.values` and `type(df.index)`.

Comment: `array(['A1BG', 'A1BG-AS1', 'A2LD1', 'A2M', 'A2ML1'], dtype=object)` and `pandas.indexes.base.Index`, respectively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error in A) is likely because you have strings or someother type of `object` in your index.  The default format specifier in `np.savetxt` appears to assume the data is `float`-like. I got around this by setting `fmt='%s'`, though it likely isn't a reliable solution.

B) doesn't yield any errors for me, using some basic examples of `Index` and `MultiIndex`.  Your error is probably due to the specific type of elements in your index.

Note that there is an easier and more reliable way to save just the index.  You can set the `columns` parameter of [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) as an empty list, which will suppress all columns from the output:

```
df.to_csv('file_name', columns=[], header=False)
```

If your index has a name and you want the name to appear in the output (similar to how column names appear), remove `header=False` from the code above.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @root's answer, if you've already deleted df after saving its index, you can do this:

```
saved_index=df.index
pd.Series(saved_index,index=saved_index).to_csv('file_name', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: if you do that you will have twice the index on each line. i would suggest to do this instead: `pd.Series(saved_index).to_csv('file_name', header=False, index=False)`